# use array in php class construct get Array to string conversion error

Tags: php

Get error Notice: Array to string conversion

what's wrong in this line 
$this->database['dsn'] = "mysql:host=$this->database['host'];dbname=$this->database['db']";

my code

```
class databaseClass {

  // data variables
  private $database;


  // Construct
  public function __construct() {

    // database info
    $this->database['host'] = 'localhost';
    $this->database['db'] = 'dbname';
    $this->database['username'] = 'root';
    $this->database['password'] = '123';
    $this->database['dsn'] = "mysql:host=$this->database['host'];dbname=$this->database['db']";


  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use complex syntax (curly braces) for the variable interpolation.

```
"mysql:host={$this->database['host']};dbname={$this->database['db']}";
```

See the "Complex (curly) syntax" section in the manual on [variable parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Using simple syntax (without the braces) PHP is just trying to insert `$this->database` into the string, which gives you that notice when it converts the array to a string.

---

Not directly related to that problem, but I'd suggest passing the connection info as arguments to the constructor. Hard coding them in the function body is a very inflexible way to do it. Try using a different database connection for testing, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$database` variable hasn't been initialised as an array before assigning values to it. Try:

```
private $database = [];
```

Comment: still error Array to string conversion in this line $this->database['dsn'] = "mysql:host=$this->database['host'];dbname=$this->database['db']";